# Gcloud ml-engine: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: package_uris Error

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am new to gcloud and I am trying to submit a ML job to gcloud by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine). I faced the error during submitting the job. Here is the full log.

> sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/models/research$ gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s`     --job-dir=gs://tf_testing/train --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz     --module-name object_detection.train     --region us-central1     --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml     --     --train_dir=gs://tf_testing/train     --pipeline_config_path=gs://tf_testing/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: package_uris Error: The provided GCS paths [gs://tf_testing/train/packages/8ec87a281aadb58d3d82462bbffafa9d7e521cc03025209704bc643eb9f3bc37/slim-0.1.tar.gz, gs://tf_testing/train/packages/8ec87a281aadb58d3d82462bbffafa9d7e521cc03025209704bc643eb9f3bc37/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz] cannot be read by service account service-499049193648@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
>     fieldViolations:
>     - description: The provided GCS paths [gs://tf_testing/train/packages/8ec87a281aadb58d3d82462bbffafa9d7e521cc03025209704bc643eb9f3bc37/slim-0.1.tar.gz,
>         gs://tf_testing/train/packages/8ec87a281aadb58d3d82462bbffafa9d7e521cc03025209704bc643eb9f3bc37/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz]
>         cannot be read by service account service-499049193648@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
>       field: package_uris

Anyone knows how to solve it? FYI, I just manually upload all the files required to storage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same problem back then I was solving "Distributed Training using GPUs on Cloud AI Platform"  lab .
Notebook for it placed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/e358fe7e3fc71edfe2addfe6376cc44f5a5058a8/courses/machine_learning/deepdive2/production_ml/solutions/distributed_training.ipynb).

The simplest idea(for resolving this issue if it occurred during lab completion) is to disable "restrict public access" for your bucket, where you try to run you job. You can do that on "Cloud Storage" > "Bucket details"  page. That instantly solved the problem for me.

Of course public access to your job artifacts is not secure approach at all. The better solution(in case you faced same problem in your working project) definitely will be granting appropriate permissions to workers that try to access you bucket with job data via `IAM & Admin service`.